# solutions of wave equation with cubic term

Tags: waves, wavefunction, field-theory, covariance, non-linear-systems

Does the following equation
$$
\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu \psi + a \psi^3 = b \psi
$$
where $\psi$ is a real function, $a$ and $b$ are real constants, have other solutions that extend beyond a one dimensional line?
From wiki: [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_interaction#Exact_solutions)

They have a solution 
$$
\psi(x) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2\mu^4}{\mu_0^2 + \sqrt{\mu_0^4 + 2\lambda\mu^4}}}{\rm sn}\left(p\cdot x+\theta,\sqrt{\frac{-\mu_0^2 + \sqrt{\mu_0^4 + 2\lambda\mu^4}}{-\mu_0^2 - 
   \sqrt{\mu_0^4 + 2\lambda\mu^4}}}\right)
$$
which only varies along $\bar{x}=t\bar{p}$, where $t$ is a variation parameter, and constant along any other direction.

For example, are there solutions which depend on a radius relative to an origin? Are there solutions that exists beyond a line?

Comment: In physics, it is the eom of [real $\phi^4$ theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_interaction).

Comment: I would suggest adding a link to or explanation that $sn(u,k)$ is a [Jacobi elliptic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html) to help the reader.